# iPhone Development, either Java with LibGDX on Eclipse OR Swift on Xcode?

Tags: java, iphone, xcode, swift, libgdx

I want to develop for iPhone. I have only a little experience with programming in general. I am tossing up between Java on Eclipse with LibGDX OR Swift on Xcode. I have developer accounts so don't worry about that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try them both and then decide.

Comment: What is your opinion though? I have tried both. And I can't decide. :(

Comment: Definitely Swift on Xcode! There is nothing like developing in an IDE that's really meant to develop native applications

Comment: Tempting...very tempting. Thanks Ben. Anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop only for iPhone/Mac, use Swift (or/and Objective-C) and Xcode. Everything will be smoother and Apps will be native. Keep in mind, though, that Swift/Xcode 6 are still in Beta, so you may encounter some difficulties if you want to ship your apps immediately. Apple should release the first stable version of Xcode with Swift before the end of the year, though, so you will need only a little bit of patience.

If you want your applications to be available in non-Apple platforms, then maybe go with Java, etc.

Side note: There is the chance that Apple makes Swift open, so developing with Swift for non-Apple platforms would be potentially possible... But I wouldn't count on it, though, at least for the near future.

Comment: Thanks heaps George. Xcode and Swift look like the right option then. Let's hope that side note follows through! Haha